# Wowza on EC2 Set up and Questions

Tags: amazon-ec2, streaming, amazon-ami, keys

I have a wowza instance installed and running on EC2, but I can't find the keypair file. I am trying to install another wowza instance on a different aws account. I have the following questions, I'd greatly appreciate your answers:

1 - Is there any way to access the files under the installed instance, without a keypair file, to check and copy the wowza configuration files and settings?

2 - Does wowza really need to have been set up to start working? I mean other than the start service command, could it have been that the installed instance would not have anything to copy from afterall? Do the ports, protocol method (rtmp), ip address, stream types, application type (vods3), need to be set manually or they work right out of the box?

3 - Any chance there'd be an EBS store type (rather than instance-store based) AMI for wowza? The problem we have now with retrieving the current settings would have been solved if we were able to make an image or create a snapshot of the running instance.

4 - Do we need to enter the License key for wowza on EC2 the same way as on a dedicated server? Is the initial set up same on both EC2 and dedicated server?

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can create a new AMI and launch it by creating a new keypair. You can also enable SSH password based authentication.

Note : You can't download the keypair again, so keep it safe

2 - Yes, you need to create and configure applications based on your requirement. see here http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?4-tutorials

3 - Wowza AMI are not available for new users, see here https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007P6KSBS/ref=portal_asin_url . But you can setup it manually. If you are going to use Video On Demand streams, Recording type application use EBS, else it's not required.

4 - Yes, same setup

Hope this helps you!